# Dynamic calculation in rdlc report

Tags: c#, report, reportviewer, rdlc

I am using visual studio 2010 and report viewer control.
I have created an rdlc report and added a table.
The columns are TaxIncluded, Tax, BeforeTax, Overoll.
Overoll column is the sum of the previous overoll and current value of 'BeforeTax'. Like so:

```
   TaxIncluded    Tax     BeforeTax     Overall

          1180    180          1000        1000
          2360    360          2000        3000
          5000    400          4600        7600
         -1250   -140         -1110        6490
```

Now, I want the user to be able to sort the table by clicking on the column's header of the table inside the report, but if he'll do so, the overall column values will be wrong. How can I achive this ?

Comment: Do you mean the report is generated correctly the first time, then after sorting it shows wrong data ?

Comment: I mean I can display it correctly the first time but only when I read the records as is. 
When I want to sort the records in the table, then the data in 'Overall' column isn't correct.

Comment: Please add more details about how you implemented the report specially the sorting functionality and the expression you used

Comment: Can you regenerate the same behavior using simpler data, report, expression